# Tilemap not rendering properly

Tags: opengl, textures, sprites, tilemap, graphics-programming

I'm making a single-screen scrolling platformer (OpenGL/SDL) and I've made a tilemap out of a 2D array, pre-sized with variables of the `LEVEL_HEIGHT` and `LEVEL_WIDTH`.  Each element in this 2D array corresponds to a position in the spritesheet that I'm loading from. In my render function, I have the following code to iterate through the matrix,and put each element into a 1D vertex buffer:

```
for (int y = 0; y < LEVEL_HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < LEVEL_WIDTH; x++) {     
            if (levelData[y][x] != 0) {
                float u = (float)(((int)levelData[y][x]) % SPRITE_COUNT_X) / (float)SPRITE_COUNT_X;
                float v = (float)(((int)levelData[y][x]) / SPRITE_COUNT_X) / (float)SPRITE_COUNT_Y;
                float spriteWidth = 1.0f / (float)SPRITE_COUNT_X;
                float spriteHeight = 1.0f / (float)SPRITE_COUNT_Y;
                float vertices[] = {
                    TILE_SIZE * x, -TILE_SIZE * y,
                    TILE_SIZE * x, (-TILE_SIZE * y) - TILE_SIZE,
                    (TILE_SIZE * x) + TILE_SIZE, (-TILE_SIZE * y) - TILE_SIZE,
                    TILE_SIZE * x, -TILE_SIZE * y,
                    (TILE_SIZE * x) + TILE_SIZE, (-TILE_SIZE * y) - TILE_SIZE,
                    (TILE_SIZE * x) + TILE_SIZE, -TILE_SIZE * y
                };
                GLfloat texCoords[] =  {
                    u, v,
                    u, v + (spriteHeight),
                    u + spriteWidth, v + (spriteHeight),
                    u, v,
                    u + spriteWidth, v + (spriteHeight),
                    u + spriteWidth, v
                };
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sSheetIds[0]);
                glVertexAttribPointer(program->positionAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertices);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(program->positionAttribute);
                glVertexAttribPointer(program->texCoordAttribute, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, texCoords);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(program->texCoordAttribute);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(program->positionAttribute);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(program->texCoordAttribute);
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, when I run the code, the textures are overlapping between tiles. Consider the following example:

**sprite sheet with tiles**

[image]

**2D Array for with the indices into the sprite sheet**

```
int levelData[LEVEL_HEIGHT][LEVEL_WIDTH] = {
        { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 },
        { 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4 },
        { 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 },
        { 0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,5,0 }
    };
```

**Tile map being rendered when the game is run**

[image]

I've tried varying the size of each tile, but the textures just seem to scale up or down accordingly. I think the problem could be with the orthographic projection, but I'm not sure. What is causing the distortion here?

[Here](https://github.com/loremIpsum1771/game_programming_cs3113/blob/master/NYUCodebase/NYUCodebase/assignment4.cpp) is the full code for reference

Comment: To me it seems more like your u and v are off rather than the acutal size not being correct. Can you provide an image of which tile-id you expect to correspond to what part of the tilesheet?

Comment: @Niels So 0 should correspond to the top left corner and 7 would correspond to the top right corner. The bottom left corner would be 16 and the bottom right corner would be 23 as the dimensions are 8 columns and 3 rows.

Comment: The resulting image looks like you divide the tileset into three horizontally, and too often vertically. My guess would be that you flipped your your u and v somewhere sinze you want to divide into three tiles vertically.